# AngularJS - How To Architect Services For Unit Testing

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I have a service that have one public method and several private methods (which the public method uses). I would like to unit test this service but the only method I can test is my public method. For the sake of unit testing, should I make my private methods public so I can unit test the methods?

Here is quick pseudo code of my service:

```
WeatherService {
    return getWeather;

    getWeather(location) {
        return fetchWeather(location).then(processData);
    }

    fetchWeather(location) {
        return $http(config);
    }

    processData(data) {
        data.temp = convertTemp(data.temp);
        data.location = convertLatLong(data.location);
        return data;
    }

    convertTemp(temp) {...}
    convertLatLong(location) {...}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript doesn't have visibility features. 'Private' methods are in fact local functions that cannot be reflected and are not reachable from the outside the scope they were defined.

This limits testability of the unit. A conventional way to improve testability is to expose all methods that are helpful for testability or inheritance and designate them as private. This can be done with Hungarian notation (`_` prefix) or otherwise (e.g. JSDoc):

```
return {
  getWeather: function() {
    return this._fetchWeather(location).then(processData);
  },
  _fetchWeather: ...,
  ...
}
```

Comment: Is it good practice to expose the private methods for the sake of testing?

Comment: There's more than one opinion on that, but I consider it good. Because pros are obvious and cons are not.

Answer (score 0):

You could create another service that exposes the key worker methods and test these independently (sticking with your pseudo code style) and then  this could be injected into your WeatherService.

```
ConversionService {
  return {
   convertTemp(temp) {...},
   convertLatLong(location) {...}
  }
}
```

OR you could blackbox test the WeatherService by mocking $http and setting various datasets in your return value so that you can then test the output of getWeather only.

If the conversion methods are particularly complex it might be better to go with the former suggestion as the tests should be more concise.

However if you haven't yet written the conversion methods and you have a well understood definition of the data input and output required, the latter suggestion will allow you to approach development in a more TDD style which favours behaviour over implementation.

One more thing, if you do extract into a conversion service it might make it easier to further implement them as filters than can be used directly in the templates against the base data. This depends on what you consider a unit and how reusable you'd like your code.